# reindexing array in php based on primary key id of database

Tags: php

I have following set of array returned by one ORM query

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '11',
            'name' => 'branch11',
            'code' => '018',
            'server_name' => '****',
            'user_name' => 'usr1',
            'pass_name' => '***',
            'database_name' => '***',
            'sct_mapping_code' => '318'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '12',
            'name' => 'Branch1',
            'code' => '001',
            'server_name' => 'SRVR1',
            'user_name' => '****',
            'pass_name' => '****',
            'database_name' => '***',
            'mapping_code' => '301'
        )
    )

)
```

I need to change it is below

```
array
('11'=> array(
                'name' => 'branch11',
                'code' => '018',
                'server_name' => '****',
                'user_name' => 'usr1',
                'pass_name' => '***',
                'database_name' => '***',
                'sct_mapping_code' => '318'
            ),
    '12'=>array(
                'name' => 'Branch1',
                'code' => '001',
                'server_name' => 'SRVR1',
                'user_name' => '****',
                'pass_name' => '****',
                'database_name' => '***',
                'mapping_code' => '301'
            )
)
```

I need to make id=>11 and id=>12 as index of new array

Comment: use a loop and reassign the value of id as new key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple loop and assign the records to a new array:

```
$newArr = array();

foreach ($yourArray as $rec)
{
    $id = $rec['id'];
    unset($rec['id']);
    $newArr[$id] = $rec;
}

unset($yourArray);  //you might unset your old array so the garbage collector would free up some memory
```

Comment: i have to go for 2 nested loop, which will slow down script\

Comment: Well you're reassigning keys and modifying entries (removing the id) so this is one way to do it. I don't believe your ORM engine will assign as result set array keys automatically. Using the same array for reassigning won't work because you gonna have collisions - the values might be overwritten.

Comment: I edited the answer slightly. Unsetting the array you're not gonna use might be a good idea

Answer (score 2):

The good thing is that in PHP, indexed array, are really also just associative arrays with keys being integers. So, you could do that as simply as :

```
$myArray = array()

foreach($objects as $obj) {
      $myArray[(int)$obj->id] = $obj;
}
```

(Modify that code to suit your needs).